# TPM Factory Reset Using PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, tpm

PowerShell on Windows 8.1 has TPM cmdlets ; one of which is the `Clear-Tpm` command.

This command won't clear ownership without a specified owner authorization value. There's no option for clearing it as is done when TPM is cleared from the TPM.msc GUI.

This seems odd, am I missing something? I understand I could create it myself.

Comment: Have you tried `ConvertTo-TpmOwnerAuth -PassPhrase "blabla"` ? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603113%28v=wps.630%29.aspx

Comment: I have tried this. It's useless to me right now because I can't clear the ownership of TPM from PowerShell to be able use it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the line below I was able to reset TPM which required a reboot as expected. After reboot a authorization value was automatically assigned:

```
    Initialize-Tpm -AllowClear $true
```